# Unable to access elements from a file that is included by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a single navbar.html and included it in all the pages of my website.j The css works fine but the javascript is unable to select elements from that navbar.

navbar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <h1>
        This is a navbar
    </h1>
</nav>
```

index.html where it is replaced with a placeholder:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="nav-placeholder"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js that is replacing the navbar and implementing a test function:

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
  });

document.querySelector('.navbar').addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
})
```

Comment: Why do you use jQuery `2.1.3` instead of the newer `3.6.0`? You're loading the nav.html, but you're already trying to assign click to a nonexistent element - before that navbar is loaded. Either use Event delegation `$(document).on("click", ".navbar", myFunction)` or use the `.load` callback function.

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 2.1.3 was released in 2014 and has has [known security vulnerabilities](https://snyk.io/test/npm/jquery/2.1.3). You should upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: I've changed the jquery, event delegation worked for me but I don't understand why was the navbar not loaded even though the command to load it comes before it is being referenced?

Comment: Well (a) You passed the function which calls `load` to the `document.ready` event handler and (b) Ajax is asynchronous and non-blocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to bind your event listener before the load function had inserted the data into the DOM.

Either use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) or move the work of binding the event listener into a callback function you pass as the second argument to the [`load` method](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: As also mentioned by Roko C. Buljian, event delegation through $(document).on("click", ".navbar", myFunction) is what worked for me.